# WaitForMultipleObjects doesnt wait until all threads finish

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

What I want are 5 threads that print something indefinitely. I used the `WaitForMultipleObjects` API to wait until the threads finish and then exit the main. But it seems to exit the main just after starting the thread. `WaitForSingleObject` seems to work fine when there is a single thread to wait for. I am not sure why I don't get the same behavior when using `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


DWORD __stdcall ThreadProc(DWORD * TID) {

    //expected this block to run infinitely.
    while (1) {
        printf("Inside Thread: %d. \n", * TID);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}


int main() {

    DWORD ThreadId;

    HANDLE lpHandles[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {

        HANDLE Threadhandle = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, &ThreadId, 0, &ThreadId);
        printf("Thread %d -> ID %d started. \n", i, ThreadId);
        
        lpHandles[i] = Threadhandle;
        
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, TRUE, lpHandles, INFINITE);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `WaitForMultipleObjects(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, TRUE, lpHandles, INFINITE)`-> `WaitForMultipleObjects(5, lpHandles, TRUE , INFINITE)`. Didn't you get at least a compiler warning?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes. I did. I am an idiot. The warning just escaped me.

Comment: However, after fixing the code I can only see the last thread's output to the console.

Comment: No, you don't. You see the output from all threads. It's just that you keep overwriting `ThreadId` with the ID of the latest thread created. Since you aren't passing a **value** into your thread functions, but a pointer, all thread functions alias the same value. Result: All threads output the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you want:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD IDs[5];

DWORD __stdcall ThreadProc(DWORD* TID) {
  //expected this block to run infinitely.
  while (1) {
    printf("Inside Thread: %d. \n", *TID);
    Sleep(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}

#define NBOFTHREADS 5

int main() {
  HANDLE lpHandles[NBOFTHREADS];

  for (int i = 0; i < NBOFTHREADS; i++) {    
    HANDLE Threadhandle = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, &IDs[i], 0, &IDs[i]);
    printf("Thread %d -> ID %d started. \n", i, IDs[i]);    
    lpHandles[i] = Threadhandle;    
  }

  WaitForMultipleObjects(NBOFTHREADS, lpHandles,TRUE, INFINITE);
  return 0;
}
```

In your code you pass the pointer to `ThreadId` to the thread, but `ThreadId` is being overwritten upon the creation of each thread, therefore all threads are displaying the same thread id.

You can simplify the code above by using [`GetCurrentThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadid) and not care about pasing the thread IDs to the thread.

```
DWORD __stdcall ThreadProc(void *unused) {
  //expected this block to run infinitely.
  while (1) {
    printf("Inside Thread: %d. \n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    Sleep(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}
...
HANDLE Threadhandle = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, &IDs[i]);
```